# SQL Server T-SQL breaking a string into a temp table for a join

Tags: sql-server-2008

We have a SQL Server Scalar Function and part of the process is to take one of the input values and do the following

'inputvalue'

Create a table variable and populate with the following rows

inputvalue
inputvalu
inputval
inputva
inputv
input
inpu
inp

Then this table is joined to a query, ordered by len of the inputvalue desc and returns the top 1.  The actual code is here

DECLARE @Result NVARCHAR(20);

```
DECLARE @tempDialCodes TABLE (tempDialCode NVARCHAR(20));

DECLARE @counter INT = LEN(@PhoneNumber);

WHILE @counter > 2
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @tempDialCodes(tempDialCode) VALUES(@PhoneNumber);
    SET @PhoneNumber = SUBSTRING(@PhoneNumber, 1, @counter - 1);
    SET @counter = @counter - 1;
END

SET @Result = (SELECT TOP 1 [DialCodeID]
FROM DialCodes dc JOIN @tempDialCodes s
ON dc.DialCode = s.tempDialCode
ORDER BY LEN(DialCode) DESC);

RETURN @Result
```

It works fine but I am asking if there is a way to replace the while loop and somehow joining to the inputvalue to get the same result.  When I say it works fine,  it's too dam slow but it does work.

I'm stumped on how to break up this string without using a loop and to a table variable but my warning light tells me this is not efficient for running against a table with a million rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you familiar with tally tables? The speed difference can be incredible. I try to replace every loop with a tally table if possible. The only time I haven't been able to so far is when calling a proc from within a cursor. If using this solution I would recommend a permanent dbo.Tally table with a sufficiently large size rather than recreating every time in the function. You will find other uses for it!

```
declare @PhoneNumber nvarchar(20) = 'inputvalue';
declare @tempDialCodes table (tempDialCode nvarchar(20));

--create and populate tally table if you don't already a permanent one
--arbitrary 1000 rows for demo...you should figure out if that is enough
--this a 1-based tally table - you will need to tweak if you make it 0-based
declare @Tally table (N int primary key);
insert  @Tally
select  top (1000) row_number() over (order by o1.object_id) from sys.columns o1, sys.columns o2 order by 1;
--select    * from @Tally order by N;

insert  @tempDialCodes
select  substring(@PhoneNumber, 1, t.N)
from    @Tally t
where   t.N between 3 and len(@PhoneNumber)
order   by t.N desc;

select  *
from    @tempDialCodes
order   by len(tempDialCode) desc;
```

Comment: Thank you i'm going to use this when I revisit that page and see how it goes. I imagine it will be this week as well.  Thanks